# underscore loop over array of objects modify certain objects and remove some objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, underscore.js

suppose i have array of objects,

```
[{"month":"03-2016","isLate":"N","transactionCount":4,"transactionAmount":8746455},{"month":"05-2016","isLate":"N","transactionCount":5,"transactionAmount":-40004952945.61},{"month":"06-2016","isLate":"N","transactionCount":1,"transactionAmount":100000},{"month":"04-2016","isLate":"N","transactionCount":6,"transactionAmount":-117189.89},{"month":"02-2016","isLate":"N","transactionCount":4,"transactionAmount":-5331000},{"month":"04-2016","isLate":null,"transactionCount":2,"transactionAmount":-4888.89},{"month":"03-2016","isLate":null,"transactionCount":3,"transactionAmount":5000}]
```

is there a function in underscore or javascript where i can loop over the item, based on some condition, remove certain objects, else modify object (add some more information into objects) and return data.

Comment: Of course, but you'll have to be a lot more specific. What is exactly the condition and output you want to have?

Comment: remove element which does not have isLate":"N", and if modify the add property to element, mm, which contains the month in string 'Jan', 'Feb'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can with plain JavaScript:

- remove certain objects: with [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- modify objects (add some more information into objects): with [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

For example:

```js
var input = [
  {
    "month": "03-2016",
    "isLate": "N",
    "transactionCount": 4,
    "transactionAmount": 8746455
  },
  {
    "month": "05-2016",
    "isLate": "N",
    "transactionCount": 5,
    "transactionAmount": -40004952945.61
  },
  {
    "month": "06-2016",
    "isLate": "N",
    "transactionCount": 1,
    "transactionAmount": 100000
  },
  {
    "month": "04-2016",
    "isLate": "N",
    "transactionCount": 6,
    "transactionAmount": -117189.89
  },
  {
    "month": "02-2016",
    "isLate": "N",
    "transactionCount": 4,
    "transactionAmount": -5331000
  },
  {
    "month": "04-2016",
    "isLate": null,
    "transactionCount": 2,
    "transactionAmount": -4888.89
  },
  {
    "month": "03-2016",
    "isLate": null,
    "transactionCount": 3,
    "transactionAmount": 5000
  }
];

// Helper array to translate month number to month name 
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

input = input
    // only get the entries which don't have isLate=N:
    .filter( o => o.isLate !== 'N' )
    // add a property "mm":
    .map( o => Object.assign(o, { mm: monthNames[+o.month.substr(0,2)-1] }) );

// Output result
console.log(input);
```

For JavaScript environments which don't have ES6 support, replace the `input =` statement with:

```
input = input
    // only get the entries which don't have isLate=N:
    .filter( function (o) {
        return o.isLate !== 'N'; 
    })
    // add a property "mm":
    .map( function (o) {
        o.mm = monthNames[+o.month.substr(0,2)-1];
        return o;
    });
```

Comment: this is good however i don't think this is compatible with IE, its giving error

Comment: @ua_boaz Do not use the arrow functions if you are not transforming the code using a ES6 transformer. I'm not sure why people use the arrow functions in their answers without mentioning the compatibility issues.

Comment: I added the ES5 code for those who use browsers that don't yet support the arrow functions introduced in ES6.

Answer (score 2):

Yes with filter()

```
var resArray = myArray.filter(x => x.transactionCount != 1);
```

In this exemple, I remove element with property transactionCount === 1